# MySQL Extract data aggregating by column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to do this extraction:
I have a table with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE APP_CONNECTIONS (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  APP_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  DB varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  USERS int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  TICKETS int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

| APP_NAME | DB | USERS | TICKETS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APP1 | DB1 | 10 | 20 |
| APP2 | DB2 | 5 | 40 |
| APP2 | DB1 | 15 | 20 |
| APP3 | DB2 | 15 | 40 |
| APP4 | DB2 | 5 | 40 |
| APP5 | DB3 | 15 | 20 |
| APP6 | DB1 | 5 | 20 |
| APP6 | DB2 | 5 | 40 |
| APP7 | DB3 | 25 | 20 |

My goal is to extract only the lines that, adding the users for each DB, exceed the number of tickets.
So something like :

| DB | APP_NAME | USERS | TICKETS | TOTAL_USERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DB1 | APP1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| DB1 | APP2 | 15 | 20 | 30 |
| DB1 | APP6 | 5 | 20 | 30 |
| DB3 | APP5 | 5 | 20 | 40 |
| DB3 | APP7 | 25 | 20 | 40 |

Thanks to everyone to anyone who can give me some ideas ...

Comment: Your task is not clear. What if `TICKETS` column contains different values in different rows for the same `DB` value? Anycase you may count total amount of users per DB using window version of `SUM()`.

Comment: You are right.
Ticket is the max number of ticket that are available for each DB. The value that can change is the User.

Comment: You don't understand... imagine that you have 2 rows: `(APP1,DB1,10,15)` and `(APP2,DB1,20,35)`. Total users amount (10+20=30) exceeds the tickets amount specified in 1st row (15) and not exceeds those from 2nd row (35)... does these rows must be returned?

Comment: In your example, the 2 rows will be:
(APP1,DB1,10,15)
(APP2,DB1,20,15)
because the ticket value is referred to the DB ( and not to the APP )
In this case, the 2 rows should be returned because the sum of USERS ( 10+20) exceeds the TICKET value ( 15)

Thanks

Comment: *the 2 rows will be: (APP1,DB1,10,15) (APP2,DB1,20,15) because the ticket value is referred to the DB ( and not to the APP )* What constraint provides the same value for `TICKETS` column in different rows? Without the constraint there is no any guarantee, the values MAY differ (moreover, someday they WILL differ, due to some error, for example). This value must be stored in separate DBs table.

Comment: Fix your design. Values in one column should not be dependent on values in another non-key column. You are risking data inconsistency like in Akina's example. Create a new table for DB and TICKETS.

Comment: Ok, i will redesign it.
Thanks for the input